# geany find special substring

Tags: replace, find, geany

I have a lot of php files and I want to find every occurance of

```
htmlentities(some var);
```

in geany, and I don't want that

```
htmlentites(some var, ENT_QUOTES);
```

got found, so it has to be something like:

```
htmlentities(...);
```

because the dots stand for an undefined character, but then I am only able to find it with a specified lenght.
What is the correct syntax to find something with a undefined length substring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions inside Search and Replace dialogs. As this little depends on you system (e.g. which grep etc.) and what you are looking in detail, [here](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#regular-expressions) is the deeplink to manual.

Comment: Thank you, I looked very carefully at the regular expressions table, and made: `htmlentities\([^,]*\);`